# How does before executing the IEnumerable<T> method, method returns result in C#?

Tags: c#, yield

Below the block of code which displays the numbers greater than 2 from MyList.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace CSharpBasics
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList.Add(1);
            MyList.Add(2);
            MyList.Add(3);
            MyList.Add(4);
            var test = FilterWithYield();
            foreach (int i in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static IEnumerable<int> FilterWithYield()
        {
            foreach (int i in MyList)
            {
                if (i > 2)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when we set break-point to line `foreach (int i in test)`, **before executing the** `foreach` **loop**, `test` variable will have the result from `FilterWithYield()`. How it is possible?.My understanding is that until iteration starts IEnumerable method never executed.

Is I am missing anything here?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Because you expanded the results in the IDE which causes the IEnumerable to execute returning all contents of MyList - regardless of breakpoints.  With the if it returns only the 3 and 4 int elements.

Comment: @Andez If Result View enumerate when we expanding it, then why break-point never it method ?

Comment: See @Rango's comments now on answer

Comment: @Andez Thank You I got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the warning - `Expanding the Result View will enumerate the IEnumerable…` By looking at the results view, you are enumerating the values.

Comment: If Result View enumerate when we expanding it, then why break-point never it method ?

Comment: @arjunkr: because the debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints if the debugger itself executes code.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is an **enumerable** - essentially an enumerator provider; when it is enumerated, the **enumerator** is fetched an iterated. Now; the enumerator and enumerable are usually be different, but the enumerable (`test`) is still *something*, and that *something* still has some state that the IDE can probe.  The IDE can *detect* enumerables, and **iterates them for you** to display the contents. This can actually be very inconvenient in some cases (where the sequence is non-repeatable). Hence the IDE did warn you about this before you clicked it - see "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable".

Comment: I believe the OP is wondering why that breakpoint in `FilterWithYield` was not hit, yet VS displayed the resulting list of `[3, 4]`, which means it has fully enumerated the enumerable.

Comment: @GSerg oh, just that? "the IDE doesn't promise to hit breakpoints when displaying things in the UI despite already being in a breakpoint" - done! it would be very incovenient to the debugging experience if expanding properties in a popup navigated you away because you hit a breakpoint

Comment: Amusingly, if you replace the breakpoint with `Debug.Print("Enumerating {0}", i)`, the debugger displays an exception information ("Specified cast not valid") instead of the `[3,4]` when you unfold the Results View (VS 15.9.3). More amusingly, if you then try to expand the `Data` property of the exception and then try to expand its Results View, the VS crashes.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank You. Got it.